# Dropdown List Causing Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu

I am using the following code with my MVC Html View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Company,
                new SelectList(ViewBag.Companies, "Key", "Value", Model.Company))
```

My controller makes the like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    ViewBag.Companies = (from a in _context.Companies 
                         select new {Key = a.Id, Value = a.Name});
    return View();
}
```

But shows the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 30:          Line 31:          Line 32:
>   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Company, Line 33:                 new
>   SelectList(ViewBag.Companies, "Key", "Value", Model.Company)) Line 34:

This code is used to so a login screen where its Username, Password and Dropdown for Company.

Comment: What is the `@model` of your view? In your Controller action you need to pass in an instance to the `View()` so something like : `return View(new YourModel());`...

Comment: but it works fine for e.g showing for example text boxes based on the model? Just not dropdowns?

Comment: It is not working because you are accessing the `Model.Company` in your helper and your `Model` is null. Just write `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Company,
                new SelectList(ViewBag.Companies, "Key", "Value"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing `Model.Company` in your view. That would be null since it is never passed from the controller.

Comment: I understand that but its for a create scenrio so there is no value for it. 
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>

Comment: The above code works fine. So i dont understnad why a dropdown doent

Comment: The difference is Html."Control"For probably interpreters that the model is null and display the control anyway. Where `new SelectList(ViewBag.Companies, "Key", "Value", Model.Company)` does not scrutinize to that level and throws the exception on Model.Company. Model is null!

Answer (score 1):

First you should set your ViewModel in your View like this:

```
@model YourClassname
```

Second, you should get your `Company` and when you returning your View you should pass your item like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    ViewBag.Companies = (from a in _context.Companies 
                     select new {Key = a.Id, Value = a.Name});
    // get your Company 
    var cmp = _context.Companies.First(); //for example

    return View(cmp);
}
```